# Datatables Switch between pages automatically

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to switch between Datatables pages automatically but I don't seem to be able to get it working. I either get a long running script and If I try adding a delay I get the following error:

> table.page(...).draw(...).delay is not a function

Below is my code that I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#calendarView').DataTable({
                });
                var pages = table.page.info().length;
                    for (i = 0; i <= pages; i++) {
                       table.page(i).draw();
                       if(i===pages){
                           i=0;
                       }
                    }


            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the code below instead to cycle through all pages with interval of 1 second.

```
var table = $('#calendarView').DataTable();
setInterval(function(){ 
   var info = table.page.info();
   var pageNum = (info.page < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 1;
   table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
}, 1000);
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1aw5cL4g/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you! Does exactly what I wanted.