# How to fix next page automatically in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

Currently i'm setting up a tables based on datatables code in [Datatables Switch between pages automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456174/datatables-switch-between-pages-automatically)
Then i found a bug, table will be slide to extra page and will return to 2nd page (not first page) if "total data mod (modulo)  num. of data displated in a page" would evaluate to 0.

for example

```
____________________________________________________________
| total data | num of data displayed in a page |  result   |  
____________________________________________________________
|   9        |            3                   |    bug    |
|   10       |            2                   |    bug    |
|   8        |            3                   |    normal |
|   11       |            3                   |    normal |
```

Below is my code that I am using
https://jsfiddle.net/0oey9tnf/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    pageLength: 7
    });
    setInterval(function(){ 
       var info = table.page.info();
       var pageNum = (info.page < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 1;
       table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
    }, 1000);   

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, it appears that `DataTables.page` works with indexes and not page numbers.
So the javascript code becomes:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 7
    });
    setInterval(function(){ 
       var info = table.page.info();
       var pageNum = (info.page + 1 < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 0;
       table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
    }, 1000);   

});
```

Try the whole thing here: https://jsfiddle.net/dz5mfyr4/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    pageLength: 6
    });
    setInterval(function(){ 
       var info = table.page.info();
       var pageNum = (info.page < info.pages) ? info.page + 1 : 0
       table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
    }, 1000);   

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tom7c2ea/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    pageLength: 7
    });
    setInterval(function(){ 
       var info = table.page.info();
       var pageNum = (info.page <= info.pages) ? info.page +1: 1;
       table.page(pageNum).draw(false);    
    }, 1000);   

});
```

hope this will works for u.

Answer (score 0):

your actual logic should be circular

`var pageNum = ((info.length + info.start) % info.pages);`

should fix the issue